# Prevent .ajaxStart() from executing on a specific Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a **loading div** or **loader** that should show up during Ajax Requests.

```
$('#loadingDiv').ajaxStart(function () {
        $(this).show();
    }).ajaxComplete(function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
```

I want the loader to show up during all Ajax Requests, but prevent it on a particular request.

I tried the following:

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'Handler.ashx',
                success: function (msg, status, xhr) {
                    $('#loadingDiv').hide();
}.....
```

But the div shows up then disappears, I don't want it to show up at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set `global` to false when making the request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Handler.ashx',
    global: false,
    ...
});
```

See the [Ajax.Events](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/) docs.

Answer (score 3):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6HcpV/2/)**

Try this

```
 $.ajax({
                    url: 'Handler.ashx',
                   beforeSend:function(){
                 if (<conditon>)                /// check your condition here
                     $('#loadingDiv').show();
                     else
                       $('#loadingDiv').hide();
                    },
                    success: function (msg, status, xhr) {
                        $('#loadingDiv').hide();
    }
    });
```

Hope this helps,Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use `global: false` in your Ajax options to make the request not trigger any [global event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/).

The [`$.ajax` docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) say about the `global` option:

> Set to `false` to prevent the global handlers like `ajaxStart` or `ajaxStop` from being triggered.

From the [`.ajaxStart` docs](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/):

> If `$.ajax()`... is called with the `global` option set to `false`, the `.ajaxStart()` method will not fire.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'Handler.ashx',
beforesend:function(){
// apply your code 
},
                success: function (msg, status, xhr) {
                    $('#loadingDiv').hide();
}.....
```

reference [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)